# How to get value (draft.DraftId = new int();)and use in the variable

Tags: asp.net, linq

In my aspx page I have a dropdownlist when I select value "Draft Document" it gets new `DraftID` (identity).
Below of this dropdown list I have upload control, and gridview that like shows files when I attached.
I have used below query for datasource of gridview but I have problem in value (_DraftId)

```
var query = from at in _DataContext.tblAttachments
                where at.DraftID == _DraftId
                select at;
```

it is null, while I have used at the top `_DraftId = (int)draft.DraftId;`.
Actually I do not know how to get value `draft.DraftId = new int();` and use it in the variable and use in another places of code.

```
Tbldraft
DraftID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
FromEmailID 

Tblattachement:
 AttachmentID BIGINT  IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Draftid BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES tblDraft(DraftID),
FileName varchar(40)  NOT NULL,
```

Aspx.cs

```
  public partial class Draft : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
  private EDMSDataContext _DataContext;
  private int _DraftId;
  private string _filePath;
  private string _filename;
  private string _filename_Ext;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void ddlDraft_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();
    if (ddlDraft.SelectedValue == "Draft Document")
    {

        tblDraft draft = new tblDraft();
        draft.DraftId = new int();
        _DraftId = (int)draft.DraftId;
        draft.FromEmailId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

        _DataContext.tblDrafts.InsertOnSubmit(draft);
        _DataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
}

protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    string fullAddress = Path.GetFullPath(filePath);
    _filePath = fullAddress;

    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

    _filename = filename.Split('.')[0];
    _filename_Ext = filename;

    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

    string contenttype = String.Empty;


    //Set the contenttype based on File Extension

    switch (ext)
    {

        case ".doc":

            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";

            break;

        case ".docx":

            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";

            break;

        case ".xls":

            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

            break;

        case ".xlsx":

            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

            break;

        case ".jpg":

            contenttype = "image/jpg";

            break;

        case ".png":

            contenttype = "image/png";

            break;

        case ".gif":

            contenttype = "image/gif";

            break;

        case ".pdf":

            contenttype = "application/pdf";

            break;

    }

   // if (contenttype != String.Empty)
  //  {


        Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

        Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
        //insert the file into database
 //   }

    tblAttachment attach = new tblAttachment();
    attach.DraftID = _DraftId;
    attach.FileName = filename;
    attach.ContentType = contenttype;
    attach.Data = bytes;
    attach.Exten = ext;
    _DataContext.tblAttachments.InsertOnSubmit(attach);
    _DataContext.SubmitChanges();
    //doctranscon.TransmitToConid = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTransmittaltoCon.SelectedValue);
    var query = from at in _DataContext.tblAttachments
                where at.DraftID == _DraftId
                select at;
    GridViewEfile.DataSource = query;
    GridViewEfile.DataBind();

}
}
```

Comment: You won't get an ID for an entity until it has been committed to the database (generally, based on auto-increment generated identifiers).

Comment: in the tbldraft the row has been inserted and it is OK. and draft.DraftId = new int(); is ok just i like to get value (draft.DraftId ),what has been inserted in database.but i do not know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking quickly at the source, I'd suggest rearranging the `SelectedIndexChanged` method to allocate the id *after* the `SubmitChanges`.  It's only after the save that the id will become available; before this, it doesn't exist.

```
protected void ddlDraft_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();
    if (ddlDraft.SelectedValue == "Draft Document")
    {

        tblDraft draft = new tblDraft();
        draft.FromEmailId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        _DataContext.tblDrafts.InsertOnSubmit(draft);
        _DataContext.SubmitChanges();
        _DraftId = (int)draft.DraftId;
    }
}
```

Also, as a side-note, I'd consider whether a) some error handling might be useful in the above snippet, and b) whether a better solution might not be found to replace the global variable for storing `_DraftId`.

HTH.

Comment: just a question, value of _Draftid is ok in SelectedIndexChanged but i need this value also in click event of upload button how i can do that? now when i use value _draftid is 0

Comment: Without seeing the full solution it's hard to suggest, but in effect, you need the click event to know about the current (new) draft.  Perhaps use a hidden field to store the new id on the page, (then add a new line to SelectedIndexChanged to allocate the new draft id to the hidden field, for later use).  Alternatives include storing it in session state, to a transient datastore, etc.  Each has pro's & con's, security implications, etc, that should be further investigated.